# Why does ohms law not work on transformers?

Tags: electromagnetism

The voltage for transformer is given by

$\frac{V_1}{V_2} =\frac{N_2}{N_1}$

if we use ohms law and assume resistance are same for both inductors,

$\frac{I_1 R} { I_2 R}=\frac{N_2}{N_1}$

but

in my book they derive using power equivalence
$I_1 * V_1 = I_2 V_2$
which gives

$\frac{V_1}{V_2}=\frac{I_2}{I_1}$

where have I made the mistake?

Comment: You're misapplying Ohm's Law.

Comment: This question is quite frequent. It has been asked before many times, for example, here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16459/voltage-and-current-in-transformers/16470#16470
If you search for "ohm transformers" you'll find many simialr questions. Please, check them.

Comment: The short answer is: because a transformer is not a resistance. A transformer is basically two coils working due to magnetic inductance, nothing to do with resistances. $V=IR$ appleis to resistances only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where have I made the mistake?

For an ideal transformer, the coils are considered to have no ohmic resistance, i.e., R = 0. That is, the coils are viewed as ideal inductors. Also, there are  no power losses in the transformer laminations due to eddy currents and no magnetic flux leakage.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For a circuit which contains capacitors, resistors, and inductors (or at least a subset of these), the full expression for the voltage is $$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}+RI+\frac Q C.$$ Mutual inductance can complicate this expression, but this hopefully gives you an idea of where your math breaks down (namely in not including the inductance term as this will be holding the majority of the voltage).