# Is $V=IR$ valid for a transformer when the input wattage is constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Edit :- Sorry I didn't clarify before. My question is not duplicate. To be specific and understandable for all, please consider the voltage generator has a constant peak wattage, like a solar panel. I read this post https://www.blueraja.com/blog/194/do-transformers-obey-ohms-law and this is not the answer I was looking for.

So, this question is based on the fact that current in the primary side can't change with the changes to the secondary side because the wattage of the voltage generator is constant and the output voltage is also constant because the solar panel is working at its peak performance. With that consider following.

I saw a video lesson on Youtube ( https://youtu.be/ubZuSZYVBng ) about a person touching 200000 V and still not get killed. The video told it was due to low current that he was not killed despite the high voltage. I wanted to try it out by myself, then when planning the transformer for the project, I got confused.

My confusion can be defined by the following scenario.

[image]

As you can see in my plan, I wanted to multiply voltage by 10000 times. Let's consider "i = 1 Amp". Secondary is not shorted so there is no current flowing in the secondary coil. There is a 1000000 V voltage difference in the two ends marked with purple lines in the secondary. ( Consider the coils have no resistance).

Now look at this scenario.

[image]

The ratio of turns in the coils is similar to the first one. So, the secondary voltage must still be 1000000 V when a current is not flowing in the secondary. Let's say we short circuited the secondary via 1Ω Resistor. Then the current flowing through the resistor must be 1000000 Amps. However, if we look at the primary the current flowing in those coils must be 1 Amp or less than it. This is against the energy conservation law. I am still a beginner student in electricity, so I think there must be some kind of theory I don't know about transformers because, I researched so much on the internet but, I am still confused. Then only possible conclusion I could arrive is that circuits in transformers do not follow ohmic laws. I don't feel my conclusion is accurate. I am looking forward for a detailed answer for this.

Comment: "I wanted to try it out by myself."  High voltages are a very unforgiving beast.  I would not  trust my life to an experiment that I had to ask Stack Exchange how it would behave.

Comment: DO NOT put your life at risk touching high voltage. In order not to have a shock hazard the output impedance  of the transformer has to be high enough to limit the available current to less than about 5-10 milliamperes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does ohms law not work on transformers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503738/)

Comment: Damn who thought someone else woudl ask the exact same doubt later on

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I read the question you commented and i still have doubts. I read another blog post blueraja.com/blog/194/do-transformers-obey-ohms-law , I think the above blog post answers your question not mine. Sorry I did not make it clear, but my doubt is slightly different. In short is, what if voltage generator has a constant peak wattage, like a solar panel. I think the blog post and your question do not answer that.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question completely to show how my question is unrelated, and then modify your question's title